# How to limit area when sliding a view with UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have setup a pan gesture to the slide view, I want to prevent the view sliding if it has been slid out. So I add this when I check `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`

```
CGPoint velocity = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender velocityInView:self.view];

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint velocity = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender velocityInView:self.view];

    if (self.slideMenuView.frame.origin.x > 0 && velocity > 0) {
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

It seems working, but if I slide the view to left then drag it to the opposite direction very quickly, the check will become invalid:

[image: screencast]

Please help me out.

UPDATE: I have uploaded the project to GitHub: [Vayn/ice](https://github.com/vayn/ice)

Comment: Did you try to play with the condition `if (self.slideMenuView.frame.origin.x > 0 && velocity > 0)` like `if (self.slideMenuView.frame.origin.x > 0 || velocity > 0)`,...?

Comment: How about checking the condition using `translation` instead of `velocity`?

Comment: @ChengYuHsu No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @anhtu I have tried it and the slide view has been __frozen__ ...

Comment: Yes, because the `velocity > 0`. How about `if (self.slideMenuView.frame.origin.x > 0) {self.slideMenuView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.slideMenuView.frame.origin.y,self.slideMenuView.frame.size.width,self.slideMenuView.frame.size.height}`. I mean instead of return, you can try to reset its origin.x = 0.

Comment: @anhtu the slide view can still get rid of the edge... http://i.stack.imgur.com/TW0xE.gif

Comment: Can you post more code?. After the if statement for return. Where you write ...

Comment: @anhtu Yes. I have uploaded the project to github:  [https://github.com/vayn/ice](https://github.com/vayn/ice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from [@PhilCai1993](https://twitter.com/PhilCai1993), we found solution for this problem finally:

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    // ...

    // Add the check at the end of the block
    if (sender.view.frame.origin.x >= 0) {
        sender.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, sender.view.frame.origin.y,
                                       sender.view.frame.size.width, sender.view.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Just checking the position of slide menu view at the end of the block after updating the frame of slide menu view.

Thanks @anhtu for helping me solve this problem!

Comment: @anhtu Thank you very much! Do you have twitter? I want to follow you :D

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use Twitter. : ). My skype: "anhtudev". In the case that you want to discuss something.

Comment: That's OK. I will register a Skype account soon.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it.

```
if (self.view.frame.origin.x > 0) {
    sender.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, sender.view.frame.origin.y,
                                   sender.view.frame.size.width, sender.view.frame.size.height);
    return;
}
```

I'm not sure. I downloaded your project. But can't build

> library not found for -lSDCycleScrollView

Comment: Ah, I use a third-party library with CocoaPods, you need `pod install` before building the project.

Comment: I tried. The slide menu view has been frozen as before.

Comment: @Vayn I can't set up it now. I will try it if I have free time. I have to go. Sorry. Really want to help you.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can put a flag `didSlidOut` somewhere before detecting gestures.